# Read each files on file_list array, and search max_value in rows on each files in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have the filelist array without extension(which is like 2, 5, 8, 11, etc..), and try to read it as a text file(2.txt, 5.txt, 8.txt, 11.txt).
And each files have 3 rows, and 513 columns, which is like..

```
        wavenumber  wavelength  PS
        0.000000e+00    inf 1.339797e+10
        2.667793e-04    2.355200e+04    2.264711e+07
        5.335585e-04    1.177600e+04    5.774260e+06
        8.003378e-04    7.850667e+03    4.347408e+06
        1.067117e-03    5.888000e+03    2.071735e+06
        1.333896e-03    4.710400e+03    1.338209e+06
        1.600676e-03    3.925333e+03    1.010330e+06
        1.867455e-03    3.364572e+03    7.951162e+05
        2.134234e-03    2.944000e+03    6.293471e+05
        2.401013e-03    2.616889e+03    5.702861e+05
        2.667793e-03    2.355200e+03    4.124521e+05
        2.934572e-03    2.141091e+03    3.946834e+05
        3.201351e-03    1.962667e+03    4.367024e+05
        3.468130e-03    1.811692e+03    4.606193e+05
        3.734910e-03    1.682286e+03    3.691915e+05
        4.001689e-03    1.570133e+03    4.260768e+05
        4.268468e-03    1.472000e+03    5.516758e+05
        4.535248e-03    1.385412e+03    9.301200e+05
        4.802027e-03    1.308444e+03    1.307440e+06
        5.068806e-03    1.239579e+03    1.739384e+06
        5.335585e-03    1.177600e+03    3.961967e+06
        5.602365e-03    1.121524e+03    9.018276e+06
        5.869144e-03    1.070545e+03    1.564086e+07
        6.135923e-03    1.024000e+03    6.533970e+07
        6.402702e-03    9.813333e+02    1.299191e+07
        6.669482e-03    9.420800e+02    6.127578e+06
        6.936261e-03    9.058461e+02    2.723106e+06
        7.203040e-03    8.722963e+02    1.135096e+06
        7.469819e-03    8.411429e+02    5.839772e+05
        7.736599e-03    8.121379e+02    5.686039e+05
        8.003378e-03    7.850667e+02    4.622423e+05
        8.270157e-03    7.597419e+02    6.013722e+05
        8.536937e-03    7.360000e+02    5.963052e+05
        8.803716e-03    7.136970e+02    7.575063e+05
        9.070495e-03    6.927059e+02    9.150109e+05
        9.337274e-03    6.729143e+02    8.281556e+05
        9.604054e-03    6.542222e+02    1.441827e+06
        9.870833e-03    6.365405e+02    2.293378e+06
        1.013761e-02    6.197895e+02    4.720661e+06
        1.040439e-02    6.038975e+02    9.183591e+06
        1.067117e-02    5.888000e+02    1.244082e+07
        1.093795e-02    5.744390e+02    2.475937e+07
        1.120473e-02    5.607619e+02    3.096345e+07
        1.147151e-02    5.477209e+02    5.709620e+07
        1.173829e-02    5.352727e+02    1.128015e+08
        1.200507e-02    5.233778e+02    1.951984e+08
        1.227185e-02    5.120000e+02    3.567358e+08
        1.253863e-02    5.011064e+02    1.038480e+08
        1.280540e-02    4.906667e+02    6.609837e+07
        1.307218e-02    4.806531e+02    3.366062e+07
        1.333896e-02    4.710400e+02    3.214113e+07
        1.360574e-02    4.618039e+02    1.068869e+07
        1.387252e-02    4.529231e+02    6.818056e+06
        1.413930e-02    4.443773e+02    4.110327e+06
        1.440608e-02    4.361482e+02    3.497202e+06
        1.467286e-02    4.282182e+02    2.220670e+06
        1.493964e-02    4.205714e+02    1.557209e+06
        1.520642e-02    4.131930e+02    1.305517e+06
        1.547320e-02    4.060690e+02    1.336280e+06
        1.573998e-02    3.991864e+02    1.055823e+06
        1.600676e-02    3.925333e+02    1.249962e+06
        1.627354e-02    3.860984e+02    2.264681e+06
        1.654031e-02    3.798710e+02    3.177218e+06
        1.680709e-02    3.738413e+02    4.535130e+06
        1.707387e-02    3.680000e+02    3.768252e+06
        1.734065e-02    3.623385e+02    9.292287e+06
        1.760743e-02    3.568485e+02    1.537548e+07
        1.787421e-02    3.515224e+02    1.766043e+07
        1.814099e-02    3.463529e+02    1.719145e+07
        1.840777e-02    3.413333e+02    3.127401e+07
        1.867455e-02    3.364572e+02    1.841132e+07
        1.894133e-02    3.317183e+02    1.283891e+07
        1.920811e-02    3.271111e+02    8.802511e+06
        1.947489e-02    3.226301e+02    6.138252e+06
        1.974167e-02    3.182703e+02    3.253741e+06
        2.000845e-02    3.140267e+02    2.274736e+06
        2.027522e-02    3.098947e+02    1.761115e+06
        2.054200e-02    3.058701e+02    1.719121e+06
        2.080878e-02    3.019487e+02    2.010613e+06
        2.107556e-02    2.981266e+02    1.804399e+06
        2.134234e-02    2.944000e+02    2.074000e+06
        2.160912e-02    2.907654e+02    1.910002e+06
        2.187590e-02    2.872195e+02    2.917329e+06
        2.214268e-02    2.837590e+02    3.900309e+06
        2.240946e-02    2.803810e+02    4.747046e+06
        2.267624e-02    2.770824e+02    8.309638e+06
        2.294302e-02    2.738605e+02    9.704105e+06
        2.320980e-02    2.707126e+02    1.337196e+07
        2.347658e-02    2.676364e+02    1.850881e+07
        2.374335e-02    2.646292e+02    2.134344e+07
        2.401013e-02    2.616889e+02    2.865988e+07
        2.427691e-02    2.588132e+02    2.796588e+07
        2.454369e-02    2.560000e+02    3.577728e+07
        2.481047e-02    2.532473e+02    2.592449e+07
        2.507725e-02    2.505532e+02    2.117858e+07
        2.534403e-02    2.479158e+02    1.466834e+07
        2.561081e-02    2.453333e+02    1.447010e+07
        2.587759e-02    2.428041e+02    8.931647e+06
        2.614437e-02    2.403265e+02    5.346297e+06
        2.641115e-02    2.378990e+02    3.370142e+06
        2.667793e-02    2.355200e+02    2.844172e+06
        2.694471e-02    2.331881e+02    2.385213e+06
        2.721149e-02    2.309020e+02    2.559934e+06
        2.747826e-02    2.286602e+02    2.235514e+06
        2.774504e-02    2.264615e+02    2.389616e+06
        2.801182e-02    2.243048e+02    2.091203e+06
        2.827860e-02    2.221887e+02    3.688845e+06
        2.854538e-02    2.201122e+02    4.157106e+06
        2.881216e-02    2.180741e+02    4.784280e+06
        2.907894e-02    2.160734e+02    6.942617e+06
        2.934572e-02    2.141091e+02    8.618190e+06
        2.961250e-02    2.121802e+02    9.034358e+06
        2.987928e-02    2.102857e+02    1.041257e+07
        3.014606e-02    2.084248e+02    1.210773e+07
        3.041284e-02    2.065965e+02    1.181222e+07
        3.067962e-02    2.048000e+02    1.478849e+07
        3.094640e-02    2.030345e+02    1.399273e+07
        And so on...
```

- So I made a 2d array, and tried to findout the MAX values of each column.

  ```
  /*openfiles according to reprogramed filelist*/
  for(i =2; i<file_count; i++) {
         strcat(filelist[i],".txt");
         if((fp = fopen( filelist[i], "r")) == NULL)
         {
                 perror("error to openfiles");
                 exit(1);
         }

         /*declare the variables*/
         char data[3][513];
         //char wavenumber[513], wavelength[513], powerspec[513];
         int COL, ROW, MAX_wavenumber, MAX_wavelength, MAX_powerspec;
         int HEIGHT,WIDTH;
         HEIGHT = 513;
         WIDTH = 3;


         //input data to new array
         for(COL = 0; COL < HEIGHT; COL++) {
                 for (ROW = 0; ROW < WIDTH; ROW++) {
                         fscanf(fp, "%s", &data[ROW][COL]);
                 }
         }

         //start of comparison of data

         for(COL = 2; COL < HEIGHT - 1; COL++) {  //number starts from the 3rd column
                 while(ROW == 1) {
                         if( atof(&data[ROW][COL]) < atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]) ) {
                                 MAX_wavenumber = atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]);
                         }
                         while(ROW == 2) {
                                 if( atof(&data[ROW][COL]) < atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]) ) {
                                         MAX_wavelength = atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]);
                                 }
                         }
                         while(ROW == 3)
                                 if( atof(&data[ROW][COL]) < atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]) ) {
                                         MAX_powerspec = atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]);
                            }
                 }
         }

         printf("MAX_wavenumber : %d",MAX_wavenumber);
         printf("MAX_wavelength : %d",MAX_wavelength);
         printf("MAX_powerspec : %d",MAX_powerspec);

    fclose(fp);
  }
  ```

## This does not start at all !!

---

Here's my full code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

char *remove_ext (char* mystr, char dot, char sep);

int main()
{
        char fname1[256],fname2[256];
        char folderpath[256];
        int mod;
        int re_mainder;
        char *tem;
        char filenameNoExtension;

        char **filelist;
        int i,j,l;
        char ***ls = &filelist;

        int file_count = 0;

        char *s;

        DIR* dp = NULL;
        struct dirent* entry = NULL;

        FILE* fp = NULL;


/*open folder*/
        printf("enter the folder path : ");
        scanf("%s",folderpath);

/*  Err message of opening directory */
        if((dp = opendir(folderpath)) ==NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"unidentified folder : %s",folderpath);
                return 0;
        }

        *ls = NULL;

/*file count*/
        while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                        continue;
                ++file_count;
        }

/* rewind the directory and need to reallocate memory for reading 18250 files */
        rewinddir(dp);
        *ls = calloc(file_count, sizeof(char*));

/*make the array of filelist*/
        file_count = 0;
        entry = readdir(dp);
        while(NULL != entry) {
                (*ls)[file_count++] = strdup(entry->d_name);
                entry = readdir(dp);
        }

/*remove the extension */
        for(i = 0; i < file_count; i++) {
                filelist[i] = remove_ext(filelist[i], '.', '/');
        }
        closedir(dp);
//loop starts at 2 for get rid of space & .
        for(i = 2; i< file_count; i++) {
                printf("%s\n",filelist[i]);
        }



/*select the mod & remainder*/
        printf("select the mod number : ");
        scanf("%d", &mod);
        printf("select the remainder : ");
        scanf("%d",&re_mainder);


/*sort files by the remainder*/
        for(i = 2; i<file_count; i++) {
                if( atoi( filelist[i] )%mod == re_mainder) { /*use atoi function for changing string to int*/
                        filelist[i] = filelist[i];
                }
                else
                        filelist[i] = "delete";
        }

//delete the  "delete" in array
        l = file_count;
        for(i = 0; i<l; i++) {
                if (strcmp(filelist[i], "delete") == 0 ) {
                        for(j = i; j < l; j++)
                                filelist[j]=filelist[j+1];
                        i--; //check again from same index i
                        l--; //Decreasing the length of the array
                }
        }
        /* resize the modified file_count */
        file_count = sizeof(filelist)/sizeof(filelist[0]);
        for(i =2; i<file_count; i++) {
                printf("%s\n",filelist[i]);
        }


        /**********           **HERE"S MY QUESTION**              **********/
        /**********openfiles according to reprogramed filelist**********/


        for(i =2; i<file_count; i++) {

                strcat(filelist[i],".txt");
                if((fp = fopen( filelist[i], "r")) == NULL)
                {
                        perror("error to openfiles");
                        exit(1);
                }

                /*declare the variables*/
                char data[3][513];
                //char wavenumber[513], wavelength[513], powerspec[513];
                int COL, ROW, MAX_wavenumber, MAX_wavelength, MAX_powerspec;
                int HEIGHT,WIDTH;
                HEIGHT = 513;
                WIDTH = 3;


                //input data to new array
                for(COL = 0; COL < HEIGHT; COL++) {
                        for (ROW = 0; ROW < WIDTH; ROW++) {
                                fscanf(fp, "%s", &data[ROW][COL]);
                        }
                }

                //start of comparison of data

                for(COL = 2; COL < HEIGHT - 1; COL++) {  //number starts from the 3rd column
                        while(ROW == 1) {
                                if( atof(&data[ROW][COL]) < atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]) ) {
                                        MAX_wavenumber = atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]);
                                }
                                while(ROW == 2) {
                                        if( atof(&data[ROW][COL]) < atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]) ) {
                                                MAX_wavelength = atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]);
                                        }
                                }
                                while(ROW == 3)
                                        if( atof(&data[ROW][COL]) < atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]) ) {
                                                MAX_powerspec = atof(&data[ROW][COL+1]);
                                        }
                        }
                }

                printf("MAX_wavenumber : %d",MAX_wavenumber);
                printf("MAX_wavelength : %d",MAX_wavelength);
                printf("MAX_powerspec : %d",MAX_powerspec);


                fclose(fp);
        }
}


//this is just for removing the extension of files
char *remove_ext (char* mystr, char dot, char sep) {
        char *retstr, *lastdot, *lastsep;

        // Error checks and allocate string.

        if (mystr == NULL)
                return NULL;
        if ((retstr = malloc (strlen (mystr) + 1)) == NULL)
                return NULL;

        // Make a copy and find the relevant characters.

        strcpy (retstr, mystr);
        lastdot = strrchr (retstr, dot);
        lastsep = (sep == 0) ? NULL : strrchr (retstr, sep);

        // If it has an extension separator.

        if (lastdot != NULL) {
                // and it's before the extenstion separator.

                if (lastsep != NULL) {
                        if (lastsep < lastdot) {
                                // then remove it.

                                *lastdot = '\0';
                        }
                } else {
                        // Has extension separator with no path separator.

                        *lastdot = '\0';
                }
        }
        // Return the modified string.

        return retstr;
}
```

Comment: What does the comment 'second row was cracked' mean?

Comment: @roelofs Informations in the second row doesn't have a right information

Comment: Ok, and can you post one of your full data files?

Comment: @roelofs ok just a moment.

Comment: Ok, so each file has 3 columns, and 513 rows ;-)  Looking at it now.

Comment: Can you post any error messages that you may be getting?

Comment: @roelofs The maximum character I can write is 30000 which I can't post all of data. But I edited it, as like the file format. And there's no Error message when I tried to compile on my mac terminal. But when it comes to the Ubuntu system, it shows me a segmentation fault [ core dump ]

Comment: What are the files I need to run your code?  I've renamed the data you provided to 2.txt, but then get a corrupted double-linked list error.  Is that what you're seeing?